# pytorch: GRU cannot update hidden_state in-place

Tags: python, pytorch

I got a problem when using pytorch to implement a GRU network:

My codes are as below:

```
import torch

class GRU_model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device):
        super(GRU_model, self).__init__()
        self.h = torch.randn((1,1,5), device=device, dtype=torch.float)

        self.GRU_1 = torch.nn.GRU(input_size=5, hidden_size=5)

    def forward(self, a):
        output, self.h = self.GRU_1(a, self.h)
        return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    learn_rate=1e-4
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model = GRU_model(device).to(device=device)
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learn_rate)

    for i in range(10):
        a = torch.randn((1, 1, 5), device=device, dtype=torch.float)
        output = model(a)
        loss = (a - output).mean()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()
```

and I got an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator_/Desktop/Graduation_Project/MIDI_Music_style_transfer/GRU_toy_in-place_hidden_states_change/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 245, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 147, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [15, 5]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

I just want to update the hidden_state in the GRU after an epoch but it just doesn't work!

I'd be really appreciated if you could me help out!

Answer (score 0):

In PyTorch, the computation graph is created for each iteration in an epoch. In each iteration, we execute the forward pass, compute the derivatives of output w.r.t to the parameters of the network, and update the parameters to fit the given examples. After doing the backward pass, the graph will be freed to save memory. In the next iteration, a fresh new graph is created and ready for back-propagation.

Because the computation graph will be freed by default after the first backward pass, you will encounter errors if you are trying to do backward on the same graph the second time. That is why the following error message pops up:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time
```

[source](https://jdhao.github.io/2017/11/12/pytorch-computation-graph/)

In your case, after specifying `retain_graph=True` you see:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [15, 5]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

The problem occurs when you try to update `self.h` in forward pass. You haven't modify it `inplace` since it's needed for grad computation. [source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gru-model-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation/57312/5?u=discort)
This one should work:

```
import torch


class GRU_model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device):
        super(GRU_model, self).__init__()
        self.GRU_1 = torch.nn.GRU(input_size=5, hidden_size=5)

    def forward(self, a, h):
        output, hh = self.GRU_1(a, h)
        return output, hh


if __name__ == '__main__':
    learn_rate = 1e-4
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    model = GRU_model(device).to(device=device)
    model.train()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learn_rate)

    def mse(output, target):
        loss = torch.mean((output - target)**2)
        return loss

    for i in range(10):
        a = torch.randn((1, 1, 5), device=device, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
        target = torch.randn((1, 1, 5), device=device)
        h = torch.randn((1, 1, 5), device=device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output, h = model(a, h)
        loss = mse(output, target)

        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: In your case, the nth epoch's h doesn't come from the n-1th epoch's output but is just reset as random matrix, that's not how GRU works. Anyway, thanks for replying.

Comment: Don't you confusing training with inference and purpose of `H`? LSTM/GRU take `H_t-1` previous hidden state and the previous step's observed data `X_t-1` to compute `H_t` and `X_hat_t`. 
During training when your data is shuffled so your model feed batches (`a` in the example) independently and passing `h` from n to n+1 epoch does not make sense. But in inference, you can pass h from current batch to the next one.

Comment: My model learns from a sequence(like a sentence), the shuffle only happens between different batches or different sequences, if you randomlize the h each epoch(a word from the sentence as input in epoch), what's the difference between a Linear layer and a GRU layer as the hidden_state in GRU doesn't inherit its former hidden_state(which means you shuffle the sentence itself which really makes no sense at all)?

Comment: It seems I got your point. `a` shouldn't be a word in a sequence, it must be a sequence of words. Look at the docs for GRU `inputs` https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html `input of shape (seq_len, batch, input_size)` - tensor containing the features of the input sequence. So in your case `a` should have the same shape (seq_len, batch, input_size). Under the hood GRU is passed hidden_state from a prev word to other and returns you a final h. If you want passing `h` in the sequence manually take a look at `torch.nn.GRUCell`

Comment: I got it, thanks, I'll try what you said.

Comment: I set a whole sequence as a single input for the GRU, it cannot learn a good model.Traditional loss functions like cross-entropy and MSE won't learn any effective features and reconstruction error with Gaussian distribution would work a bit better but still with no semantic features learned. I have to step back to one work per input.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is the hidden_state shouldn't participate the computation of the gradients backpropagation.
So just adding one line `self.h = self.h.detach()` as below that will certainly solve the problem:

```
    def forward(self, a):
        output, self.h = self.GRU_1(a, self.h)
        self.h = self.h.detach()
        return output
```